# Boolean operation when assigning value in Ruby

Tags: ruby, boolean-expression

I am new to Ruby and I did the following:

```
c = {}
# Some code in the middle
c['a'] = c['a'] or 0
```

Now I would expect this to work like this: if `c['a']` is `nil`, then `c['a'] or 0` would return 0. So the value of `c['a']` should be 0.

However the value of `c['a']` is `nil`. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`or` is not the same as `||` in Ruby](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/). What you have becomes grouped like so:

```
(c['a'] = c['a']) or 0
```

which will basically do nothing. You should use `||` instead:

```
c['a'] = c['a'] || 0
```

or simply:

```
c['a'] ||= 0
```

Note that `and`/`&&` has the same behavior as `or`/`||`.

Comment: Is "`or` is not the same as `||` in Ruby" your favorite saying?

Comment: @muistooshort It seems to come up often enough `:P`. I actually have it (and a few other common things) as clipboard snippets to leave in comments on SO. (And thanks for fixing my silly typo!)

Comment: Ooh..tricky, tricky. From the article above, I guess it's best to use `and` and `or` only as control modifiers. Thanks for the link and the answer.

Comment: @Aishwar Correct. Some Ruby programmers advocate never using `and`/`or` because of the "weirdness" about them, but as long as you understand the difference there's nothing wrong with using them where they should be.

Answer (score 2):

`=` has a higher precedence than `or`, so you need parentheses to make it do what you expect:

```
c['a'] = (c['a'] or 0)
```

Or just use `||` as usual :)

Comment: Yup, seems like I should be using `||` for most things :)